# Using ctype_alnum() with spaces

Tags: php

I was trying to check if a string is alphanumeric using `ctype_alnum()`. Problem is, the string can have spaces in it, and `ctype_alnum()` returns false. Is there a method to check if a string is alphanumeric even with spaces in php, or is there a hack to use ctype_alnum() with spaces.

Comment: Look for regular expressions. Like, preg_match could be a good start I think.

Comment: Already doing that, but there no built in php function that can do it?

Answer (score 6):

you could use `str_replace` to remove the spaces before checking it in `ctype_alnum()` no need for regex. but you will need to use regex for other characters.

```
$string1 = 'df 34 df sdf 34 234 234 sdf sdfds ';




if(ctype_alnum(trim(str_replace(' ','',$string1))))
{
    echo 'baz'; 

}else{
    echo 'bar';

}
```

at the moment there is no function like that which you are looking for.

Comment: If you're already using `str_replace()` to cut out spaces you don't need to use `trim()` here. :)