# PHP only Cyrillic in input without JavaScript

Tags: php, cyrillic

Is there a way to make only Cyrillic to be able to put in input/post? I did it with `if(ctype_alnum($imeiprezime) == false)` and it's working but I can't add spaces. I want to allow inputs like `Ilija Popivanov` and `Илија Попиванов`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ctype\_alnum() with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804342/using-ctype-alnum-with-spaces)

Comment: i sat it  its not useful for me

Comment: Why? It meets your requirement of not using JS.

Comment: IDK its not working for me

Comment: I made the same code as before again http://prntscr.com/b1coby And its not working

Comment: Do you also want to allow hyphens (`-`)?

Comment: nope :P Only cyrillic and spaces

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111298/discussion-between-ile-popivanov-and-laurel).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this:

```
$string1 = ' Ilija Popivanov Илија Попиванов';


if(!preg_match('/[^\p{Cyrillic}\p{L} ]/u',$string1))
{
    echo 'pass'; 

}else{
    echo 'fail';

}
```

Essentially, if there are any non-Cyrillic non-space, or non-letter characters, `preg_match` will return true.